# JQuery and Bootstrap's Typeahead, it seems to ignore some JSON results?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

This one is really vexing me, hopefully someone can figure out what is going on.

The JS:

```
        $('#search').typeahead({
    source: function(typeahead, query){ 
        $.ajax({
            url: "/autocomplete_bs.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "q="+query ,
            dataType: "JSON",
            async: true,
            success: function(data){
                if (data == null) {
                    data = '{"name":"name","url":"url"}';
                }
                typeahead.process(data);        //If the returned object is not a null json object, THEN process it.
            }
        });
    },
    property: 'name',
    items:8,
    onselect: function (obj) { 
        window.location = obj.url;
    }
});
```

The autocomplete_bs.php is here: http://examine.com/autocomplete_bs.php?q=xxxx

You can test out the auto-complete here: http://examine.com/ (top right)

What is boggling is that some results show, some don't.

- examine. com/autocomplete_bs.php?q=bacopa - shows
- examine. com/autocomplete_bs.php?q=aging - shows
- examine. com/autocomplete_bs.php?q=life - does not show?
- examine. com/autocomplete_bs.php?q=food - only shows the first result, does not show the second
- examine. com/autocomplete_bs.php?q=creat - shows multiple results, but skips 'What is Creatine Nitrate?'

Console does not show any error that would explain this. Any clue?

(Sorry as my reputation is too low and I forgot my other primary login I had to break the URLs).

Comment: Have you inspected the ajax response to see what it contains? also, `data = '{"name":"name","url":"url"}'` should be `data = {"name":"name","url":"url"}`, at that point in the code data is a javascript object, not a json string. Why are you using `async: false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, turns out I forgot that typeahead has a matcher function that filters out what it shows.

So this line fixed it:

```
matcher: function () { return true; },
```

Answer (score 0):

examine.com/autocomplete_bs.php?q=life - does not show anything because your "name" field in the returning object doesn't contain any 'life'

It returns:

```
[{"name":"Stack - Anti-Aging","url":"http://examine.com/autocomplete_go.php?q=life&url=stacks/anti-aging.html"}]
```

So in other words, you set up Typeahead to show ***only*** those results which "name" contains the actual string (ex. 'life'), even if the server return more items..